# Java : BOLD with iText in PDF Generation doesn't work correctly

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I use iText for generating PDF, from a XML file, with content in HTML. Everything is working, except one little thing.
When I have a bloc of text containing a part in BOLD, the BOLD doesn't appear in the resulting PDF file. If I have a complete phrase in BOLD, it's working fine.
Examples :

```
<DIV><FONT face='Arial' size='10'><B>The BOLD for this phrase works</B></FONT></DIV>
<DIV><FONT face='Arial' size='10'>The BOLD for <B>this part of the phrase </B> doesn't work</FONT></DIV>
```

With 'Italic' or 'Underline', I can do the same test but I don't have the problem. It's working...
A little precision : if I use a tag `<B>` combined with a tag `<U>` or `<I>`, for a part of bloc of text, it's working too.
Example :

```
<DIV><FONT face='Arial' size='10'>The combination of <B><I>BOLD and something else (U or I)</I></B> works fine.</FONT></DIV>
```

For the context : WebApp with struts, the PDF is not saved as a file but sent to the navigator as a response. As suggested by an answer, I update my version of iText from 1.4.8 to 5.5.7.
For the HTML code saved in a xml file, you can see examples above.
For the Java code (I picked up the code from severals long methods. I hope I forgot nothing...).

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baoutLettre = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
Document document = new Document();  
PdfWriter myWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baoutLettre);  
handleHeaderFooter(request, response, document, Constantes.Type_LETTRE);  
document.open();  
String lettreContent = FileHelper.readFile("myLetter.xml");  
XmlParser.parse(document, new ByteArrayInputStream(lettreContent.getBytes("UTF-8")), getTagMap());
document.close();
ByteArrayOutputStream outTmp = new ByteArrayOutputStream(64000);
PdfCopyMerge pdfCM = new PdfCopyMerge(outTmp);
pdfCM.addDocument(baoutLettre.toByteArray());
pdfCM.close();
ByteArrayOutputStream outPDF = addPageNumber(outTmp.toByteArray(), soc, dicoEdition, request);
outPDF.writeTo(request.getOutputStream());
```

And for the class PdfCopyMerge :

```
public class PdfCopyMerge {

private ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
private Document document = null;
private PdfCopy writer = null;

public PdfCopyMerge(ByteArrayOutputStream stream) {
    super();
    outStream = stream;
}    
public int addDocument(byte[] pdfByteArray) {
    int numberOfPages = 0;
    try {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfByteArray);
        numberOfPages = reader.getNumberOfPages();
        if (this.document == null) {
            this.document = new Document(reader.getPageSizeWithRotation(1));
            this.writer = new PdfCopy(this.document, this.getOutputStream());
            this.document.open();
        }
        PdfImportedPage page;
       for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPages;) {
           ++i;
           page = this.writer.getImportedPage(reader, i);
           this.writer.addPage(page);
       }
       PRAcroForm form = reader.getAcroForm();
       if (form != null) {
           this.writer.copyAcroForm(reader);
       }
   } catch (Exception e) {
      logger.error(e.getMessage(),e);
   }
    return numberOfPages;
}
```

Does anybody face the same problem ? I look for any helping ideas ...
Thanks.

Comment: Works with current release (5.5.7) of iText and XML Worker.

Comment: Can you switch fonts? If so try to switch explicitely to a bold font. (I don't know iText well enough to know whether they change font for bold, or just fatten up the current font).

Comment: It's not necessary to change Font, because the one I use is good when I have a complete phrase ... In my examples, the first DIV is working fine but not the second one.

Answer (score 1):

Try the lastest version 5.5.7. Everything works fine.
https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/tags